# "Error inflating class fragment" when trying to add a map v2 fragment to activity_main

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

When I add map fragment:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".MainActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

to activity_main.xml I get that error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.koba.ogloszenia, PID: 3073
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.koba.ogloszenia/com.example.koba.ogloszenia.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class fragment 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
...
```

My **MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment MapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    MapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
    mMap = Map;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

My **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.koba.ogloszenia">

<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have included in depedencies

- com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1
  and
- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1

I also have checked "Google Play services" in SDK Tools.

I also looked similar posts but that didn't solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<meta-data>` elements must be within the `<application>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml` but out of the `<activity>` element.